# Is it okay to run Django API server with root permissions?

Tags: django, security

I am running django server, using `gunicorn`. Apart from `gunicorn`, I have a layer of `nginx` as a load balancer and using `supervisord` to manage `gunicorn`.

From the perspective of security is it fine to run my `gunicorn` server with `sudo` permission? Is there any potential security leak?

Also, does it makes any difference if I am a superuser and not running process with `sudo` permission as in any case I have `sudo` permissions as the user.

Comment: If Django is running as root, that means Django can do anything root can (everything). Django is running *your code*. Are you confident there's no *oopsie* in there which may `rm -rf` your hard disk, or somehow allow a user to run code through an `eval` somewhere…?

Comment: @deceze I am not sure about that but if that is true, irrespective of `sudo`, attacker can run that, right? Surely, might not be able to delete everything but can delete things accessible to user running server?

Comment: Exactly, and since the user running the server is root, that's *everything*.

Comment: @deceze so  basically, I will have to make a new user, give it permission to code base and run everything as that user? Right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does it need to run as root?

If it doesn't, don't run it as root.

Even better, add a separate user for the app and run it as that user.

Comment: Hey, what permission should I give to that user to access the code base? Should it be read/write/execute or all of them, as it needs to write logs for sure, execute the code as well. Thanks

Comment: To execute Python code you need to only be able to read it. But that aside, just have the app user own the code and the logs, etc, e.g. `/home/myapp/app` for code, `/home/myapp/logs` for logs, `/home/myapp/media` for Django media...

Answer (score 1):

I believe the answer to question "is it ok to run xxx with root permissions" should not be "If it doesn't, don't run it as root." but rather a clear "NO".

Every single server and framework is designed to be run without root rights.

What can go wrong? In case you have a vulnerability allowing to remotely execute code on the server you would be simply giving root rights to whoever can exploit it. In case one of your developers in team does something stupid like deleting the root directory, it will be deleted. You don't want that a single app running on the server disrupts your whole system, do you?

Answer (score 0):

It is not a good practice to run any external network facing application with root user privilege.

Consider a scenario where your uploaded file is not validated or sanitized ( file upload vulnerability). If someone uploads some vulnerable file and executes it. Consider that file to have implemented reverse shell. Then it gets easier to take down your server.